# jq: join one array against multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I'm trying to integrate joining one array with multiple others into my jq command.

This is a small example of my json document:

```yaml
{
    "items": [
        {
            "metadata": {
                "name": "pod1"
            },
            "spec": {
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "name": "container1",
                        "volumeMounts": [
                            {
                                "mountPath": "/path1",
                                "name": "mount1"
                            },
                            {
                                "mountPath": "/path2",
                                "name": "mount2"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "container2",
                        "volumeMounts": [
                            {
                                "mountPath": "/path3",
                                "name": "mount1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "volumes": [
                    {
                        "name": "mount1",
                        "persistentVolumeClaim": {
                            "claimName": "claim1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "mount2",
                        "emptyDir": {}
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to output the name of all pods, its containers, and the containers mount points & names, and in the end only selecting mounts whose volumes have the key `persistentVolumeClaim`, e.g.:

```
pod1;container1;mount1;/path1;claim1
pod1;container2;mount1;/path3;claim1
```

So far I was able to extract the pod-name, container-name and the mount name and path:

```bash
jq -r '.items[]
    | {pod:.metadata.name, c:.spec.containers[]}
    | {pod:.pod, container:.c.name, mount:.c.volumeMounts[]}
    | [.pod, .container, .mount.name, .mount.mountPath]
    | join(";")'
```

This give the following output:

```
pod1;container1;mount1;/path1
pod1;container1;mount2;/path2
pod1;container2;mount1;/path3
```

Now I need to join the `volumes` array with each `volumeMounts` array in `containers` and afterwards select for only those with the `persistentVolumeClaim` key. I got it to work to join two arrays, but I wasn't able to integrate it in the command above to join `volumes` with each `volumesMounts` in the `containers` array in the command above:

```bash
jq -r '.items[]
    | .spec.containers[].volumeMounts+.spec.volumes
    | group_by(.name)
    | map(add)
    | .[]
    | select(.persistentVolumeClaim)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which builds an index per item, then transforms the data into structured objects, and finally creates an array to join:

```
.items[]
| INDEX(.spec.volumes[]; .name) as $index
| { pod: .metadata.name }
+ (
    .spec.containers[]
    | {
        container: .name,
        mount: JOIN($index; .volumeMounts[]; .name; {name: first.name, path: first.mountPath, claim: .[1].persistentVolumeClaim.claimName})
    } | select(.mount.claim)
)
| [ .pod, .container, .mount[] ]
| join(";")
```

Output:

```
pod1;container1;mount1;/path1;claim1
pod1;container2;mount1;/path3;claim1
```

Answer (score 2):

While traversing, you could store all parts needed into variables for reference. This includes creating a lookup index using the names under `.volumes` as keys, realized here as object using `INDEX`.

```bash
.items[] | .metadata.name as $meta
| .spec | INDEX(.volumes[]; .name) as $volumes
| .containers[] | .name as $name
| .volumeMounts[] | select($volumes[.name].persistentVolumeClaim.claimName)
| [$meta, $name, .name, .mountPath] | join(";")
```

```
pod1;container1;mount1;/path1
pod1;container2;mount1;/path3
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/l9buIwBxrMn)

Comment: Missing the claim name in the output, but otherwise a great answer! So probably something like `.volumeMounts[] | $volumes[.name].persistentVolumeClaim.claimName as $claimName | select($claimName) | [ ..., $claimName ] | join(";")`

Comment: @knittl My understanding of the Q was that the name was only added to be used for filtering. But yes, if it should be included, just append it to the last array (before joining). To facilitate its access, the index can be prepared accordingly, e.g. `INDEX(…) | .[] |= .persistentVolumeClaim.claimName` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/cgfKVNTtJhL)